# css default vertical-align with inline-block

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

Here is the [code](https://jsfiddle.net/ngrhhppt/5/).

I have typical form with label, input and helper:

[image]

The code:

html:

```
<div class="container">
  <span class="label">Label:</span>
  <div class="el">
    <input>
    <span>helper helper helper</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.container {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.label{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
.el{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60%;
}
input{
 width: 50%;
}
```

The problem is that *Label:* aligned opposite second row. I know how to fix that: i can use `float: left;` or `vertical-align: top;` in the `.label` class, but i want to know, *why is that happening?* Why *Label:* jump to second row?

p.s. Sorry for my english.

Comment: why your input tag is not closed? This is not the best practice..

Comment: @Amitsingh "Input Must have a start tag and must not have an end tag": [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the default value for `vertical-align` is `baseline`, which...

> Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent

For reference, here is the article on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)

Comment: Ok, but why the baseline of parent (`div.container`) jumped to the second row?

Comment: Because the baseline will be the bottom of .el (the tallest rendered element).

Comment: [Here](http://www.impressivewebs.com/css-vertical-align/) is an article explaining vertical align a bit clearer. [Here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align) are the W3C docs regarding vertical align.

Comment: According to [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-linebox/#vertical-align-prop): "**baseline**: _Align the 'alphabetic' baseline of the element with the 'alphabetic' baseline of the parent element. If the inline element doesn't have an 'alphabetic' baseline, align the bottom of the box, including its margin for replaced elements, with the parent's 'alphabetic' baseline._" Since `.el` doesnt have _alphabetic_ baseline, its baseline is bottom of the box. So all child align with the bottom. But i'm not sure, because in docs is nothing about  baseline of the block elements (which is `.el`).

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one;

```
 .inner {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 3px 5px;
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/edge0703/pen/iHJuA)

Comment: `width` property doesn't work with non-replaced inline elements: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width)

Comment: ya just a minutes sir

Answer (score -1):

I think due to the `display:inline-block` defined is creating this situation..

Better use `display:inline`
This will solve your problem...

And here is the code

CSS

```
.container {
  outline: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  height: 100px;
}
.label{
  display: inline;
  width: 50%;
}
.el{
  display: inline;
  width: 60%;
}
input{
 width: 50%;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
      <span class="label">Label:</span>
      <div class="el">
        <input />
        <span>helper helper helper</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `width` property doesn't work with non-replaced inline elements: [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/width)